# How to write assert for a method in test class

Tags: unit-test

I need to write system.assert for the following method in my test class:

```
public PageReference back()
    {
        return new PageReference('/apex/Rforce_VehicleFinderForCase_Page?Id='+accountId);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Write a test class and in class's test method you can write assert as:

```
    // myController is instance of your visualforce controller which contains `back()`
    // accountId, you will need to insert an Account record in test class and assign it to `accountId`

    System.assert(myController.back().getUrl(),'/apex/Rforce_VehicleFinderForCase_Page?Id='+accountId);
```

Read about [Pagereference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) class to know how I used its method to apply assert.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below

```
PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/Rforce_VehicleFinderForCase_Page?Id='+'001xxxxxxxxxxxx');
System.assert(back(),p);
```

**Note:**

You should pass your original Id in place of 001xxxxxxxxxxxx

Hope it helps.